# Spring Boot 2.3.0.RELEASE /actuator/sessions endpoint is missing

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

For the life of me I can't get the `/actuator/sessions` endpoint to show up. My configuration:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include = *
management.endpoint.sessions.enabled = true
```

All the docs say it should be there, but it's not. In fact, I'm missing `auditevents`, `flyaway`, `jolokia`, `logfile`, `liquibase`, `prometheus`, and `sessions`.

Is there some package I need to include?

Comment: and do you actually have something for those endpoints? So are you actuyally using flyway, liquibase, spring session etc. if those technologies aren't in use the endpoints won't be there either.

Comment: Can you link your dependencies and why you think the Sessions endpoint should be active?

Comment: The Spring Boot actuator docs say these endspoints should exist, and make no mention of dependent libraries. Now, I can see that most of the mentioned ones there might not show up, but because this is a webapp that definitely has HttpSessions, and there are other HTTP-related endpoints present in my running app, I assumed the sessions one would be there, too.

It would be great if the actuator docs made it clear what to expect.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked with a sample project of spring boot `2.3.0.RELEASE` for jolokia and prometheus - and by default the fact that you add the following dependencies should make it work:

For jolokia:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
    <artifactId>jolokia-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

For prometheus:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In the case of jolokia you should even see the following log message:

```
<date goes here> INFO 5908 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar   : Registered '/actuator/jolokia' to jolokia-actuator-endpoint
```

There are also properties like:
`management.endpoint.jolokia.enabled` that should be "true"

So, in short, it should be there...

You can see the full "list" of exposed endpoints by issuing a GET request to:

`<host>:<port>/actuator/mappings`

Comment: Can you link to the changelogs for requiring this for Spring Sessions actuator endpoints?

Comment: As I understood , the question wasnt only about sessions endpoint but about many endpoints that are claimed to be missing. I couldnt quickly check sessions, liquidbase and flyway but could relatively easily check the jolokia and prometheus/micrometer stuff... Hopefully OP will find it useful

Comment: I'm really only interested in examining the sessions in my running webapp, I just mentioned the others as additional info.

Comment: Noted, in this case my answer is not that relevant indeed, sorry. @Rick, so you dont see /sessions mapping when you run `/actuator/mappings`, right?

Comment: The sessions endpoint at the level of source code is here: `https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.3.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/session/SessionsEndpoint.java` So please make sure that this class gets loaded (put a breakpoint in its constructor or something).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the sessions actuator only works if you are using clustered sessions via Spring-Session - see: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8278

If you are not using clustered sessions (and so not using Spring-Session), then it looks like you have to implement your own actuator to list the sessions.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (2.3.3.RELEASE) the `SessionsEndpointAutoconfiguration` is not able to find a bean of type `FindByIndexNameSessionRepository`

```
SessionsEndpointAutoConfiguration#sessionEndpoint:
  Did not match:
     - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.session.FindByIndexNameSessionRepository; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans of type org.springframework.session.FindByIndexNameSessionRepository (OnBeanCondition)
```

However, if I manually define a `SessionEndpoint` bean it successfully injects the `FindByIndexNameSessionRepository` and creates an endpoint eventually.

```
@Bean
SessionsEndpoint sessionsEndpoint(FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<? extends Session> sessionRepository){
        return new SessionsEndpoint(sessionRepository);
}
```